# BeautifulSoup: Extract the data in the text after a particular span

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know there's loads of similar questions to this out there, I just can't figure out my specific example.

On [this](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/O00203#sequences.html) page, I want to extract the number '121,320' from the line: 'Mass (Da):121,320'

I can see from BeautifulSoup that this is where I want:

```
</div><a class="show-link" href="#" id="O00203-show-link" style="display:none">Show »</a></div><div class="sequence-isoform-rightcol"><div><span class="sequence-field-header tooltiped" title="Sequence length.">Length:</span><span>1,094</span></div><div><span class="sequence-field-header tooltiped" title="The mass of the unprocessed protein, in Daltons.">Mass (Da):</span><span>121,320</span>
```

I was trying this:

```
import urllib
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

uniprot_list = ['O00203']
for each_id in uniprot_list:
        data = requests.get('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/' + each_id + '#sequences.html')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')


        #prints all spans
        print(soup.find_all('span'))

        #prints empty list
        print(soup.find_all('span',title_='The mass of the unprocessed protein, in Daltons.'))
```

The closest I've gotten was by trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003342/extracting-particular-data-with-beautifulsoup-with-span-tags) answer on SO:

```
    div1 = soup.find("div", { "class" : "sequence-isoform-rightcol" }).findAll('span', { "class" : "sequence-field-header tooltiped" })
    for x in div1:
            print(x.text)
```

The issue is that is prints out:

```
Length:
Mass (Da):
```

without the actual values.

How do I extract the mass from each page that I have? In this case 121,320?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression `re` to search the text and then use `find_next('span')`

```
import re
import urllib
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

uniprot_list = ['O00203']
for each_id in uniprot_list:
        data = requests.get('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/' + each_id + '#sequences.html')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.find('span',text=re.compile("Mass")).find_next('span').text)
```

**Output**:

```
121,320
```

Or if you have Bs4 4.7 and above then you can use following css selector.

```
import urllib
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

uniprot_list = ['O00203']
for each_id in uniprot_list:
        data = requests.get('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/' + each_id + '#sequences.html')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.select_one('span:contains("Mass (Da)")').find_next('span').text)
```

**Output**:

```
121,320
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = '''
<html>
<body>
</div><a class="show-link" href="#" 
id="O00203showlink"style="display:none">Show»</a</div><div class="sequence-isoform- 
rightcol"><div><span class="sequence-field-header tooltiped" title="Sequence 
length.">Length:</span><span>1,094</span></div><div><span class="sequence-field-header 
tooltiped" title="The mass of the unprocessed protein, in Daltons.">Mass (Da):</span> 
<span>121,320</span>'
</body>
</html>
''' 


soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'lxml')
span_text = [x.text for x in soup.findAll('span')]
#op
 ['Length:', '1,094', 'Mass (Da):', '121,320']
```